# How to make a dictionary containing dictionaries in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I attempted the syntax in the following way:

`var Days: [String: (Dictonary [Int: Int])] = ["ADay: : [:], "BDay" : [:], "CDay" : [:], "DDay:" : [:]]`

I wish to then set them later like so:

`Days.ADay = [1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7]
 Days.BDay: [Int: Int] = [1:8, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5:4, 6:5, 7:13]`
etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Please consider to use the goodies of object oriented programming: custom  struct or class.

Comment: Have you read the [Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID105) section of "The Swift Programming Language" book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a nested dictionary in Swift is easy. In its simplest form, the most intuitive way is:

```
let dict = ["key": ["nestedKey": ":)"]]
```

In your case, for starters, your quotations are mismatched.

Next, you're overthinking what a dictionary is and how you instantiate it. You're trying to build a predefined dictionary with nested keys (which are actually immutable). If you want to do it your way, don't worry about pre-defining keys. When you're ready to assign, do:

```
var days: [String: Dictionary] = []
days["ADay"] = [1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7]
```

If you need something more complex, or something more structured than that, try using a [Struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) instead. This is the "Swift" way of doing things, allowing you to structure a complex set of conforming (statically typed!) data. Example:

```
struct Days {
    var ADay = [Int: Int]()
    var BDay = [Int: Int]()
    var CDay = [Int: Int]()
    var DDay = [Int: Int]()
}

var days = Days()

days.ADay = [1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7]
```

Comment: Hi! var days: [String: Dictionary] = [] raises an error: "Use [:] to get an empty dictionary literal". When I add ":", I get an error "Cannot assign value of type '[String : Dictionary]' to type '[String : Dictionary<Key, Value>]'", any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Here are your examples with legal syntax:

```
var Days: [String: [Int: Int]] = ["ADay": [:], "BDay" : [:], "CDay" : [:], "DDay:" : [:]]

Days["ADay"] = [1:1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:5, 6:6, 7:7]

Days["BDay"] = [1:8, 2:1, 3:2, 4:3, 5:4, 6:5, 7:13]
```

Another way to declare your type is `var Days: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<Int, Int>>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a shorthand type declaration it would look like this.

```
var twodDict: [String : [String : Int]]
```

In other words:

```
var twodDict: [OuterKey : [InnerKey : StoredObjectorValue]]
```